# Plotting symbolic function using symsum

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I'm attempting to plot the temperature distribution with respect to time.

I found that the solution to the Heat Equation with initial temperature distribution of $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$ is

$$u(x,t)=\frac{\pi}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{\pi n^2}((-1)^n-1)e^{-n^2t}\cos(nx)$$

So far I was able to come up with the following Matlab code:

```
syms t;
r = symsum((2/(pi*n^2))*((-1^n)-1)*cos(n*x)*exp(-(t*n^2)),n,1,1000);
grid on
ezplot(r+(pi/2),[-1,1],[-1,1])
```

When I try to run this get the following error:

```
??? Undefined function or variable "X".

Error in ==> ezplot>ezimplicit at 252
[X,Y] = meshgrid(X,Y);

Error in ==> ezplot at 153
    hp = ezimplicit(cax,f{1},vars,labels,args{:});

Error in ==> sym.ezplot at 71
   h = ezplot(char(f),char(y),varargin{2:end});

Error in ==> fp at 26
ezplot(r+(pi/2),-1,1,-1,1)
```

I know that I have to adjust something small, since I was able to plot the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}=e^x$ on $[0,1]$. The big difference between this example and my problem is that what I'm trying to plot has two variables (which I noticed Matlab didn't recognize per the error message), but I read online that I can specify the range for it in the argument of `ezplot`, yet I still came up with an error.

I'm wondering if there's an easier way of approaching this problem. I'm fairly new to Matlab and learn as I go.

Comment: I've edited your post for readability. You have a typo in your `ezplot` line, which I fixed. I think you mean `ezplot(r+(pi/2),[-1,1],[-1,1])`? Where you actually running that?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yeah, I found that problem out after I posted this and still came up with an error, which just said that I have error on the line 2 $r=symsum...$, which I don't think has a problem.

Comment: I just found this site, http://www3.nd.edu/~nancy/Math30650/Matlab/Demos/demo10-5b/demo10_5_b.html which seems to give me what I want, hopefully something will work.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I agree – this is a perfectly fine question. I've upvoted it to get you back to zero. Sorry that I never got around to an answer on this one. I assume you're also defining `x` and `n` as symbolic, i.e. `syms t x n;`? Your code works fine in R2014b. What `version` of Matlab are you using? The Symbolic Math tool box has changed and improved a lot in recent versions. Do you actually need to evaluate/plot this sum symbolically, as opposed to numerically?

Comment: Thank you for responding and upvoting. Also, I'm using R2011a. I was luckily able to use a different approach to get what I wanted, but I will definitely check out how Symbolic Math tool has changed over the recent versions of Matlab.

Answer (score -1):

```
syms x t real;
syms n integer;
r = symsum((2/(pi*n^2))*((-1^n)-1)*cos(n*x)*exp(-(t*n^2)),n,1,1000);
grid on;
ezplot(r+(pi/2),[-1,1],[-1,1]);
```